# Given a current velocity and a fixed input energy, how much faster will a relativistic particle be?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, acceleration

The relativistic kinetic energy of a particle with mass $m$ and velocity $v_0$ is $$m c^2 (\gamma_0 - 1) \textrm{ where } \gamma_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_0^2}{c^2}}}$$

I would like to know how quickly the particle will be moving ($v_1$) after energy $E_i$ is added to the system in the direction of positive acceleration.

I presume that I can use the following equivalence:

$$E_i = E_1 - E_0 = m c^2 (\gamma_0 - 1) - m c^2 (\gamma_1 - 1)$$

I believe my goal is to solve for $v_1$ (from $\gamma_1$ by analogy) given $E_i$ and $v_0$.

I have two questions:

First, is this approach correct, or am I misunderstanding how kinematics works?

Second, how can I solve the equation for $v_1$? I find that the algebra is beyond me and I haven't been able to leverage online solvers to improve my situation. Any suggestions as to how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is correct.  As for solving (analytically) I've not made the attempt and I agree it looks messy.  I have had some experience with numerical solutions for given values of $v_0$ and $E_i$ and find that extreme precision (more than available in calculators at the time) is required if you attempt to use the exact equations.  A Taylor expansion of $\gamma$ greatly simplifies the calculatiojn.

Comment: @matthew-piziak The $1/2$ factor in your kinetic energy formula is incorrect. I assume you used it in view of the non-relativistic limit, but there it actually comes from the Taylor expansion of $\gamma$ in terms of $v/c$. Also, indices $0$, $1$ in the rightmost expression in your 2nd eq. must be reversed. As for the algebraic solution, it's not that complicated, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the kinetic energy. Working with the total energy $\gamma m c^2$ produces the same result.

Assuming both the **total** initial energy $\bar E_0 = \gamma_0 m c^2$ and the additional energy $E_i$ are known, write $\gamma_1 mc^2 = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\beta_1^2}} = \bar E_0 +E_i$ for $\beta_1 = \frac{v_1}{c}$, then
$$
\sqrt{1-\beta_1^2} = \frac{mc^2}{\bar E_0+E_i} \;\;\Rightarrow \;\; \beta_1 = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{mc^2}{\bar E_0+E_i}\right)^2}
$$